# Dispatch redux action after Apollo Query component returns result

Tags: reactjs, redux, apollo, react-apollo

Using the old way:

```
graphql(GET_PROJECTS_BY_USER_ID, {
    options: ownProps => ({
        skip: !ownProps.loggedUser.id,
    }),
    props: ({ data }) => {
        return data;
    },
});
```

I could catch the list of projects inside `componentWillReceiveProps` lifecycle and dispatch the redux action there:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (!nextProps.loading && this.props.loading) {
        this.props.setProjects(nextProps.getProjects);
    }
}
```

Now I'm trying out Apollo's `<Query/>` component and I can't figure out how to properly dispatch an action:

```
render() {
    return (
        <Query
            query={GET_PROJECTS_BY_USER_ID}
            skip={!this.props.loggedUserId}
        >
            {({ loading, data: { getProjects: projects } }) => {
                if (loading) return 'Loading ...';

                this.props.setProjects(projects); // no good

                // return projects
            }}
        </Query>
    );
}
```

This will cause the following warning:

> Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render` or another component's constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to `componentWillMount`.

The problem is that by using `<Query>,`componentWillMount` will no longer be called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new `Query` component uses the [render props](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html) pattern. The function that's passed in as the child of the component is called inside `Query`'s render method, which means you don't have access to any other lifecycle methods *for that component* inside the function. To get around that, you have to create an additional component that implements the lifecycle method(s) you need. Just one way to do that:

```
class DoSomethingOnce extends Component {
  componentWillMount () {
    this.props.action()
  }
  render () {
    return this.props.children || null
  }
}

<Query
  query={GET_PROJECTS_BY_USER_ID}
  skip={!this.props.loggedUserId}
>
  {({ loading, data: { getProjects: projects } }) => {
    if (loading) return 'Loading ...';
    <DoSomethingOnce action={() => setProjects(projects)}>
      // whatever else you're going to render
    </DoSomethingOnce>
  }}
</Query>
```

Alternatively your component with `componentDidMount` could just do all the rendering instead of passing the buck to its children. You can always also use a library like [reactions/component](https://github.com/reactions/component).

This is really no different than when you were using the `graphql` HOC -- you still had to wrap that HOC around a component that implemented `componentDidMount`.

Comment: Thanks! Guess I'll stick to the graphql HOC.